# Accept credit card number or paypal information in ios app

Tags: ios, paypal, credit-card

I have an application in which i need to add a screen which will accept paypal information or credit card detail and then that will be passed to server for charge processing.

i have doubt whether this is possible or not, if possible then whether apple will approve it or not.

My requirements are

1) customer will buy a ride 
2) driver will accept that and driver should get paid.

Customer will add credit card detail and send to server where money will be deducted

driver will ask for payout so driver will be asked paypal detail and sent to server and server will process the transaction pay to driver.

So its clear that we can not use in app purchase as its not buying the digital items.

Please suggest if there is any alternate way to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at using Braintree for my app's financial services. Struggling with it, but might be good for you to look at as well.